# Unable to add horizontal scrolling on mat card list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a horizontal scroll to a list of mat card(coming from another component using ngfor), but unable to get it done .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use overflow-x: scroll on your Div(list) in CSS/SCSS